# Turn markdown table into html table

Tags: css, markdown, gist

I´m currently using a tool, which creates a little informational report over solidity smart contracts with some usefull informations in it, that I want to partially display on the website I´m working on.
The tool is called solidity-metrics (https://github.com/ConsenSys/solidity-metrics) and can be used as CLI or as a library in your backend for example, which is what I want to use.
I´m sending files to my backend, which than scans those solidity files with the metrics tool.
It creates can create an object with a lot of meta-data using `metrics.total()` but it also can create a markdown string using `metrics.generateReportMarkdown()`.

It includes taledata, which is only displayed in the markdown, not in the `metrics.total()` object, so I need to somehow turn it into html.

The table content from the markdown looks like this:

```
| Type | File   | Logic Contracts | Interfaces | Lines | nLines | nSLOC | Comment Lines | Complex. Score | Capabilities |
|========|=================|============|=======|=======|===============|==============|  
|  | ./uploads/contracts/ProjectName.sol | 1 | **** | 564 | 535 | 308 | 152 | 221 | **<abbr title='Uses Assembly'></abbr><abbr title='Payable Functions'></abbr><abbr title='Uses Hash-Functions'></abbr><abbr title='create/create2'></abbr>** |
|  | ./uploads/contracts/ERC2981.sol | 1 | **** | 48 | 37 | 24 | 7 | 15 | **** |
|  | ./uploads/contracts/IERC2981.sol | **** | 1 | 18 | 14 | 3 | 10 | 3 | **** |
|  | ./uploads/contracts/MockERC721.sol | 1 | **** | 27 | 27 | 19 | 1 | 18 | **** |
|  | ./uploads/contracts/TokenName.sol | 1 | **** | 285 | 262 | 157 | 46 | 159 | **<abbr title='Uses Assembly'></abbr><abbr title='Uses Hash-Functions'></abbr>** |
|  | ./uploads/contracts/Originals.sol | 1 | **** | 142 | 128 | 83 | 22 | 81 | **<abbr title='Uses Hash-Functions'></abbr>** |
|  | ./uploads/contracts/SutterTreasury.sol | 1 | **** | 23 | 23 | 17 | 1 | 20 | **<abbr title='Payable Functions'></abbr>** |
|  | **Totals** | **6** | **1** | **1107**  | **1026** | **611** | **239** | **517** | **<abbr title='Uses Assembly'></abbr><abbr title='Payable Functions'></abbr><abbr title='Uses Hash-Functions'></abbr><abbr title='create/create2'></abbr>** |
```

What I´ve tried and found out so far:
So the table actually kinda looks like normal markdown to me, but somehow, when trying to throw it inside a .md files it still doesn´t look like it should:

[image: what it should look like]

I figured out, that they have linked this github.css file in their credits:
https://gist.github.com/tuzz/3331384
tryed to import it into the .md file but it also didn´t seem to work, don´t even know if that makes sense to import a css file into a .md file...

To come to an end, does anyone have an idea on how to turn this markdown into html, which looks like the image I posted above (which I created with the function, which you can build into vs code, where you can mark the files, right click and scan them using metrics)?

Edit: So I figured out, that the equal signs, splitting the headers from the table body could be replaced by hyphens, which would work out fine in the markdown. I could solve that by replacing all "=" with "-", but that would destroy the rest of the markdown file, because there are also other usecases for the equal sign.

Comment: There are a few `npm` packages that convert `markdown` into `html`. [This package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked) looks promising. If you aren't using JS, I'm sure there are other similar packages for different languages as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Tho the problem is, that the way the tables are written in the markdown string, which the metrics tool is generating, are "invalid" in usual markdown because they use equal signs instead of casual hyphens for splitting the table-body from the table-header, which leads to the markdown not accepting it as a table...

Comment: Ah, I see. What about finding a substring that starts and ends with `|` and replacing its `=` with `-`? It's less than ideal but might help you get the job done.